# Simplify extension Methods (combine)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to have an extension method apply to two or more classes?

Essentially hoping to clean up code (that isn't necessarily messy) like this where we have two classes

```
GameObject go = new GameObject();
Transform t = new Transform();
```

And we want to operate on them in the same way...

```
GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
```

But the result is "messy" if one extension method is created...

```
go.transform.EnableMeshRenderers(true);
t.EnableMeshRenderers(true);
```

As of now the way we are doing it simply duplicating the extension method with the type needed to get the result we want:

```
go.EnableMeshRenderers(true);
t.EnableMeshRenderers(true);
```

Is it possible, or rather, how does Unity have the GetComponent(s) methods extended to both `GameObject` and `Transform`? Are they likely to be doing this by the same process?

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this Transform trans, bool _enable, string _name = "")
    {
        foreach (MeshRenderer meshRenderer in trans.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
            else if (meshRenderer.gameObject.name.ToUpper().Equals(_name.ToUpper()))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
        }
    }

    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this GameObject go, bool _enable, string _name = "")
    {
        foreach (MeshRenderer meshRenderer in go.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
            else if (meshRenderer.gameObject.name.ToUpper().Equals(_name.ToUpper()))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit***:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `Component` instead of `GameObject` or `Transform`?

Comment: @user1781290 How then does GameObject and/or Transform call the extension method as changing to component produces an error on GameObject/Transform.ExtensionMethod() of does not contain a definition for and the best extension method overload requires a receive of type Component?

Comment: GetComponentsInChildren should be a method of Component, if I'm not mistaken. If you use `public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this Component...)`, where do you get the error?

Comment: @user1781290 See attached image in op edit

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, forgot, that GameObjects does in fact NOT inherit from Component. Then maybe call the transform method from the gameobject method? Then you'll have at least no duplicate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they do not share a common interface for these methods (their common ancestor is [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html)), it is not possible to write a single extension method which will accept either type of argument.

That said, because GameObject's have Transforms (and vice-versa), it is possible to avoid the bulk of the duplication of both methods:

```cs
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this Transform trans, bool _enable, string _name = "")
    {
        foreach (MeshRenderer meshRenderer in trans.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
            else if (meshRenderer.gameObject.name.ToUpper().Equals(_name.ToUpper()))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
        }
    }

    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this GameObject go, bool _enable, string _name = "") => go.transform.EnableMeshRenderers(_enable, _name);
}
```

The other way around would also work:

```cs
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this GameObject go, bool _enable, string _name = "")
    {
        foreach (MeshRenderer meshRenderer in go.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
            else if (meshRenderer.gameObject.name.ToUpper().Equals(_name.ToUpper()))
                meshRenderer.enabled = _enable;
        }
    }

    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this Transform trans, bool _enable, string _name = "") => trans.gameObject.EnableMeshRenderers(_enable, _name);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. This makes more sense +1

Answer (score 2):

These two functions are nearly identical. They both operate on a collection of `MeshRenderer`. The only difference is how they obtain that collection.

You can extract the common part and then call it from both extensions:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this Transform trans, bool enable, string name = "")
    {
        var renderers = trans.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        EnableMeshRenderers(renderers, enable, name);
    }

    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(this GameObject go, bool enable, string name = "")
    {
        var renderers = go.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        EnableMeshRenderers(renderers, enable, name);
    }

    public static void EnableMeshRenderers(
        this IEnumerable<MeshRenderer> meshRenderers, bool enable, string name)
    {
        foreach (MeshRenderer meshRenderer in meshRenderers)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                meshRenderer.enabled = enable;
            else if (string.Equals(meshRenderer.gameObject.name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                meshRenderer.enabled = enable;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I exposed the new method as a public extension as well, but it could be a private method.